# linked-list: why extend a single-node list by adding the new node to head->next, but not head=head->next and then adding to head

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

*A simple linked-list code:*

```
#include<iostream>

struct node {
  int    data;
  node*  next;
};

int main() {
  node *head, *head1;
  head = new node;
  head1 = head; //we'll use head1 to print the entire list at the end

  head->data =  2;
```

the following block of code, commented out, doesn't add new node to the list

```
  /* head = head->next;
  head = new node;
  head -> data = 20;*/
```

but the (seemingly similar) below method works, and we print the entire list in the end

```
  head->next = new node; 
  head = head->next; 
  head->data = 20;
  
  while (head1 != nullptr) {
    std::cout<<head1->data<<std::endl;
    head1 = head1->next;
  }
}
```

Since both *head* and *head->next* are of type node*, how to understand that `head->next = new node;` works, but not `head = head->next; head=new node;`

Comment: The question is unclear. What is not working, could you show it in the code instead of showing the working code.

Comment: You can't do `head = head->next` because there isn't anything IN `head->next`.  `head->next` is garbage.  You have to put an object there before you can switch to it.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks. It may initially contain garbage value but why should that matter?  Memory was initially created for the next (pointer) variable to hold an address value and why can't the head move to next and rewrite the address value by pointing to a 'new' node? (sorry if I'm missing something obvious)

Comment: Yes, there is a cell called `head->next` but it contains garbage.  When you say `head = head->next`, now `head` contains that garbage.  It does not POINT to the old `next` field.  You have lost the pointer to the list.  This is just like writing `int i;` / `cout << i;` / `i = 7;`.  Do you expect that to print "7"?

Comment: @AjayA You are getting confused between the pointer and what is being pointed at. `head = head-next` does not make `head` point at `head->next`. If **copies** the pointer `head->next` (which is garbage) to `head`, so now `head` is garbage as well. It's **exactly** the same as `int i = 1; int j; i = j;` Variable `j` is garbage and executing `i = j;` makes `i` garbage as well. Assignment of pointers works exactly the same as assignment of non-pointers. There's nothing special about pointers, as the saying goes.

Comment: `head = head->next;` would read an uninitialized variable. That's enough for your program to have undefined behavior, meaning that the program could do pretty much anything.

Comment: @john7 thanks. Now it's clear to me and I also see the meaning of Tim Roberts' earlier comment. I was imagining that *head = head->next* will somehow make *head* jump to *head->next* position (since both are of the same type) and then starts pointing to nullptr.  I now remember that for two pointers *p1* and *p2*, *p1=p2* simply means that *p1* also points to where *p2* is pointing at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown works.

If you try `head = head->next; head=new node;` it will fail because `head->next` at this point is null, so now `head` is null. You can assign a new node to it, but that does not affect the `next` member of the object `head` was previously pointing to.

Here's how things start out:

```
+----------+
| *head    |
+----------+
     |
     |
     V
+----------+               +--------+
| node     |<--------------| *head1 |
| -------- |               +--------+
| data = 2 |       ??????
| *next ---------->?????? 
+----------+       ??????
```

Now, if we try what you're asking about, we end up with:

```
+----------+               +--------+
| node     |<--------------| *head1 |
| -------- |               +--------+
| data = 2 |       ??????
| *next ---------->?????? 
+----------+       ??????

+----------+
| *head    |
+----------+
     |
     |
     V
+-----------+             
| node      |
| --------- |           
| data = 20 |      ??????
| *next ---------->?????? 
+-----------+      ??????
```

Note that `head1` still points to the original node containing the value `2`, but there is nothing linking that node to the node containing the value `20`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  head = head->next; 
  head = new node; 
  head -> data = 20;
```

This code doesn't add a new node because, once we do `head = head->next` now `head` points to `NULL`. Now that we have created a new node but still previous node points to `NULL` only. To test this we can store head temporarily in a `temp` node before doing `head = head->next` and print the `temp->next` once the assignment is done. You will still see `temp->next` as `NULL`.

To avoid this behaviour we first create a node and then assign it to `head->next`.

Answer (score 0):

> how to understand that `head->next = new node;` works, but not `head = head->next; head=new node;`?

Changing the value of the variable `head` will not change `head1->next`. It is the same reason why `head = head->next;` will not magically update `head1` to the same.

It might help to visualise what happens. When your main function has executed `head->data =  2;` we have this situation:

```
      ┌─[node*]─┐    ┌─[node]───────────┐
head1:│     ────────►│       ┌─[int]───┐│
      └─────────┘    │ data: │  2      ││
                     │       └─────────┘│ 
      ┌─[node*]─┐    │       ┌─[node*]─┐│
head: │     ────────►│ next: │  ─────────────► (undefined)
      └─────────┘    │       └─────────┘│  
                     └──────────────────┘
```

The value in `head->next` is undefined: it might be `NULL` or it might be an address of unallocated memory, or be an address of memory allocated for something else, ...etc. It is undefined.

After you execute `head = head->next;` we have this:

```
      ┌─[node*]─┐    ┌─[node]───────────┐
head1:│     ────────►│       ┌─[int]───┐│
      └─────────┘    │ data: │  2      ││
                     │       └─────────┘│ 
      ┌─[node*]─┐    │       ┌─[node*]─┐│
head: │     ──────┐  │ next: │  ─────────────► (undefined)
      └─────────┘ │  │       └─────────┘│  ┌─►  
                  │  └──────────────────┘  │
                  └────────────────────────┘
```

So `head` now has an undefined value -- the same undefined value as the `head1->next` pointer.

Some observations here:

- There is no way to keep using the same undefined address and have a node allocated *there*. `new node` will allocate memory and return a (fresh) pointer to it.
- If you assign something to `head`, it will not change the pointer value in `head1->next`. And if you would assign something to `head1->next` it will not change the pointer value of `head`: they are separate pointers that currently happen to point to the same undefined spot.

So when you now do `head = new node`, (and `head->data = 20`) we get this:

```
      ┌─[node*]─┐    ┌─[node]───────────┐
head1:│     ────────►│       ┌─[int]───┐│
      └─────────┘    │ data: │  2      ││
                     │       └─────────┘│ 
      ┌─[node*]─┐    │       ┌─[node*]─┐│
head: │     ──────┐  │ next: │  ─────────────► (undefined)
      └─────────┘ │  │       └─────────┘│  
                  │  └──────────────────┘
                  │  ┌─[node]───────────┐
                  └─►│       ┌─[int]───┐│
                     │ data: │  20     ││
                     │       └─────────┘│ 
                     │       ┌─[node*]─┐│
                     │ next: │  ─────────────► (undefined)
                     │       └─────────┘│
                     └──────────────────┘
```

As you see, nothing happened to `head1->next`. You now have two separate linked lists, which both have an undefined pointer in their last (and only) nodes. This means that iteration over either list with the `while` loop will lead to undefined behaviour and likely an error.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my view, if you're going to use C++, *use C++*. Just changing `malloc` to `new` in a spot or two isn't giving you real C+++.

I'd start by adding a `ctor` to the `node` struct:

```cpp
struct node {
  int    data;
  node*  next;

  node(int data = 0, node *next = nullptr) 
    : data(data), next(next) 
  { }    
};
```

With this, inserting a new node at the head of the list is:

```cpp
// our head pointer:
node *head = nullptr;

// Insert a new node with the value 1 at the head of the list:
head = new node(1, head);
```

The user shouldn't be dealing with that directly though. We want an interface they can use cleanly.

```cpp
class linked_list {

    struct node {
        int data;
        node *next;

        node(int data = 0, node *next = nullptr) : data(data), next(next)
        { }
    };

    node *head = nullptr;
    node *tail = nullptr;
public:
    // add a new node at the front of the list:
    void add_head(int new_value) {
        // add new node before head.
        head = new node(new_value, head);
        // if this is the first node in the list, it's also the tail:
        if (head->next == nullptr)
            tail = head;
    }

    // add a new node at the tail of the list:
    void add_tail(int new_value) {
        // if the list is empty, adding at the tail is the same as
        // adding at the head:
        if (tail == nullptr)
            add_head(new_value);
        // otherwise, add the new node after the current tail
        // and update tail to point to the new node:
        else {
            tail->next = new node(new_value, nullptr);
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }

    void show() {
        for (node *current = head; current; current = current->next)
            std::cout << current->data << "\n";
    }
};
```

Much of the idea of classes is to present a relatively abstract, easy to use interface that protects them from the ugly details of traversing the list, inserting nodes correctly, assuring that it remains a proper linked list at all times, etc.

```cpp
int main() {
    linked_list ll;

    ll.add_head(2);
    ll.add_tail(20);
    ll.show();
}
```